# JAXB Element for same class name in different package should be same(using @XMLTYPE eg:"user")

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We have two packages:

1. com.yash.user
2. com.indore.user

Now when we create JAXB Element for both it shows the below exception:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://api.yash.com/v3}user".
Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

  this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.yash.user
        at protected com.indore.user 

-->  this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.yash.user
```

But for both the classes we need a same name @XMLTYPE (name="user").

So can we have a solution for this?

Comment: please post code what you have now

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
//TODO :- Name should be user in Type
@XmlType(name = "user", namespace = "http://api.yash.com/v3", propOrder = {"userName"})
//TODO :- Name should be user in RootElement
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class UserDTO{

 @XmlElement(name = "userName")
 protected String userName;

 public String getUserName() {
  return userName;
 }

 public void setUserName(String userName) {
  this.userName = userName;
 }
}

Comment: package com.indore.user;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
//TODO :- Name should be user in Type
@XmlType(name = "user", namespace = "http://api.yash.com/v3", propOrder = {"firstName"})
//TODO :- Name should be user in RootElement
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class UserDomain{

 @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
 protected String firstName;

 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
}

Comment: They both are my XSD class for both we have @XMLTYPE(name="user")

Comment: How we can used Same XML type name of different package ? Please suggeset and Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: ^ Please move this code into the question using the edit button - voting to close for now. Code really doesn't below in comments.